# Find the coefficient of $x^{25}$ in $(1 + x^3 + x^8)^{10}$

Tags: combinatorics

> Find the coefficient of $x^{25}$ in $(1 + x^3 + x^8)^{10}$.

Here is my solution I am looking to see if it is correct or if there is another way to do it, thanks!

The only way to form an $x^{25}$ term is to gather two $x^8$ and three $x^3$ . Since there are ${{10}\choose{2}} =45$ ways to choose two $x^8$ from the $10$ multiplicands and $8$ ways to choose three  ${{8}\choose{3}}= 56$ ways to choose $x^3$ from the remaining $8$multiplicands, the answer is using the product rule  $45×56 = 2520$.

Comment: $2520$ is right!

Answer (score 2):

Your proof looks OK, and your answer is correct.

---

However, I would write a little more justification for the sentence:

> The only way to form an $x^{25}$ term is to gather two $x^8$ and three $x^3$

How do you know this is true?

Comment: through $2\cdot 8 + 3\cdot 3 + 5\cdot 0$?

Comment: @fr14 Sure, but how do you know that this is the **only** way to get $x^{25}$? How do you know there isn't another possibility?

Comment: I am not sure!.

Comment: @fr14 Then I suggest you give it some thought.

Comment: is there another possibility?

Comment: @fr14 Well sure, you can always fully write out the expression. But your way is the best, it just needs one extra step.

Comment: oh well could you help me with this? I am not sure

Comment: @fr14 I could, but you haven't even made an attempt yet, so I won't.

Answer (score 2):

A formal way:
$$(1 + x^3 + x^8)^{10}=\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}{k}x^{3k}(1+x^5)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{10}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{10}{k}\binom{k}{j}x^{3k+5j}.$$
Now $25=3k+5j$ for $ 0\leq j\leq k\leq 10$ is solved iff $(k,j)=(5,2)$ and
$$[x^{25}](1 + x^3 + x^8)^{10}=\binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{2}=2520.$$

Answer (score 1):

Expressions like above can be evaluated by the multinomial Theorem:

$(a+b+c)^n = \sum_{k,l,m;k+l+m=n} \frac{n!}{k!l!m!}a^kb^lc^m$.

This sum means you sum over all possible $k,l,m$ with the condition that $k+l+m=n$.

Now you set $n=10,a=1,b=x^3,c=x^8$ and you obtain now that the $x^{25}$ Terms are obtained when $3l+8m=25$ for integer numbers $l,m$. This equation is satisfied only for $m=2,l=3$. Thus you obtain $k = 10-2-3=5$. It is $a^kb^lc^m = x^{25}$ and the resulting binomial coefficient is $\frac{10!}{5!2!3!} = 2520$. With above formula you obtain that the factor is $2520$ and that is correct!